# Вопрос по поводу boxing - unboxing, работа со стеком - кучей

Tags: c#

1.хотел бы узнать простыми словами как и зачем производится упаковка и распаковка значимых типов в C#.
2. Объявляя массив мы выделяем место в куче для элементов массива, тогда где хранится сама ссылка на эти данные (на стеке?)

Comment: Зависит от того, куда вы эту ссылку положили. Если это локальная переменная, то стек, если поле класса, то куча. Если оно в структуре, то смотрим дальше, как именно происходила аллокация памяти под эту структуру.

Comment: Боксинг - это когда вы делаете апкаст структуры к object, анбоксинг - в обратном направлении.